# How to get rid of the oscillatory behaviour in the fermionic functional?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, grassmann-numbers

The Gaussian fermionic integral is evaluated to be

$$
I = \int \prod_{i,j}d\theta^*_i d\theta_j \exp\left(-(\theta^*_iM_{ij}\theta_j+c^*_i\theta_i+\theta^*_ic_i)\right)=N \det M e^{c^*_iM_{ij}^{-1}c_j}
$$

where the $c$'s and $\theta$'s are Grassmann variables.

The fermionic vacuum functional is found to be

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}N\int\mathcal{D}\Psi \exp\left(i\int dt\left(\frac{1}{2}\overline{\Psi}(i\sigma_3\frac{d}{dt}-w+i\epsilon)\Psi+\overline{\Theta}\Psi\right) \right) = \tilde{N}\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}\int \int dt_1dt_2\overline{\Theta}(t_1)G_F(t_1-t_2)\Theta(t_2), \right)
$$

with $G_F$ the Feynman Green's function

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\left(i\sigma_3\frac{d}{dt}-w+i\epsilon \right)G_F(t-t')=\delta(t-t').
$$

Question: Do I need to regularize this vacuum functional before applying the Gaussian integral formula? I can't see why after the integration I get a $-i$ in the exponent.